# I have timestamp of one event in one of the log files and I want to take out system statistics from other log file using this time stamp

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

f1.txt:

> ts1 : start process ts2: end process

f2.txt

> ts1 1MB/s  2 I/Os

I want to combine ts1 from f1 and f2 and form an event=> ts1 start process 1MB/s 2I/Os

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and after that edit your question to make clear what you are asking. At the moment you just telling the world, what you like to do.

Comment: Added quotes for file text